# Yii, yiic and console

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

In the installation instructions for Yii it is nescessary to use console and command line utility - yiic.

Well, on my shared hosting I don't have ssh access.

This is why I have following questions:

1. How often and for what reasons will I have to use console?
2. Is there a way to avoid using yiic?
3. May I run yiic on local server and then just transfer everything to the final web server?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you might get the best answers from the support team (or forums) of that framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer from Yii forums:

No, you don't use yiic on production server to generate code. You only use it on your dev machine which you normally should have full control over it.

The yiic code generation tool is just a way to help you speed up your development. If you are familiar with yii, you can create an application from scratch without using yiic.